# Present as Popover segue is blank, but Present Modally is not blank

Tags: swift, interface-builder, xcode6

I created a segue from a button to a ViewController in IB. When I choose Present as Popover, none of the controls in the main View show up. I know the main View is displayed, because I have changed the background color to red. However, none of the child controls of the View appear at runtime. If I set the segue type to something else, for example, Present Modally, then the child controls show up. I am using AutoLayout and Class Sizes. This is an iPad app.

I have created a new blank app and tested out the scenario on that project and it works fine. So there is something up with my project. I have no error messages or warnings from Interface Builder. I have cleaned the project and restarted the simulator.

Any ideas on why my controls aren't showing up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the project was corrupt. Eventually the code sense failed and and objects disappeared out of the storyboard. I created a new project, moved my code over, and the popover works as expected.